# Using MVC.NET 5 with Entity Framework for Developing a REST API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am considering using MVC.NET 5 with Entity Framework for the development of a REST API to serve up data for consumption by a few Websites. Is there any compelling reason to wait for MVC.NET 6 or is there a best practice/more common framework for developing REST APIs. The reason I am focused to MVC is so I can enter/edit data via forms that reflect my database to more easily manage my REST data, but I am open to other options if there are more common pursuits.

My front end development is heavily focused towards HTML5 and a few JS libraries such as Angular and Backbone due to the design patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to built a stand alone Web API without mixing it with MVC 5, if you want to do it the right way use OWIN middle ware and add the components needed to build the API.
For the front end and if you are going to build SPA, start new empty project which will hold only your SPA, and this project will talk to your RESTful API.
For sure you need to allow CORS on the back-end API so it will accept calls coming from your SPA.
You can read more about how you structure this on this post. http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/